# Batch script to display a message box when a specific network printer is selected

Tags: batch-file, networking, printers

I am trying to create a batch file to display a message box when a specific printer is selected. I am not sure how I would do this as it is a network printer and therefore not directly connected to the computer. I want the message to say "Please remember to collect your printout."

Thanks

Comment: If you can use PowerShell, Get-Printer is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you could do to trigger the message but you could use this batch script for the message.

```
Taskkill /f /im wscript.exe 2>> Log.txt 
If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
 Attrib -R -S -H "%Temp%\done.vbs"
 If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
  Echo Could not delete file "%Temp%\done.vbs"

 )
)
> "%Temp%\done.vbs" ECHO x=msgbox("Please remember to collect your printout." ,6, "Print")
start "" wscript "%temp%\done.vbs
```